# Completely remove a WSP from SharePoint

Tags: deployment, solution-package, best-practices

What is the best way to completely remove a WSP from SharePoint? SO when you reinstall it again from scatch it thinks it is a clean install?

Answer (score 12, accepted):

We can either manually do it through central admin or by using powershell commands.

I would prefer doing this through powershell

To uninstall and remove Farm solutions use the Uninstall-SPSolution and Remove-SPSolution cmdlets (Use -WebApplication attribute if the solution has webapplication-scoped resources):

```
Uninstall-SPSolution –Identity MySharePointSolution.wsp –WebApplication http://webapplication  

Remove-SPSolution –Identity MySharePointSolution.wsp
```

To uninstall and remove Sandbox solutions use the Uninstall-SPUserSolution and Remove-SPUserSolution cmdlets:

```
Uninstall-SPUserSolution –Identity MySharePointSolution.wsp –Site http://webapplication/sitecollection  

Remove-SPUserSolution –Identity MySharePointSolution.wsp –Site http://webapplication/sitecollection
```

Comment: Remember that any artifacts that were added to the Content DB (for example .webpart files in de Web Part Gallery) will still exist after the WSP is completely removed from the farm.

Comment: Also remember to deactivate any features in the solution prior to removing it